# Validating DataGridView through Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, validation, ms-access, datagridview

I currently have a data grid that is holding the information from an Access table. The details in the database are employee details e.g. Name, Number, Postcode, Address, Pay rate etc.

What I need is to be able to validate the data that's being entered for data type, presence and extreme data, but I have no idea what to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Server side or client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for the Datagridview `CellEndEdit` event (if you wish to check the entered value AFTER editing for that cell has finished). Among the parameters for this event is a `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`. This has a `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` so you'll be able to retrieve which cell is being edited (in case you want different checks based upon which column you'r editing).

Raymond

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you mean. Would it be possible for a message box to appear if one of the cells didn't meet the validation rules?

Comment: Yes, if you're in a windows form project you could pop-up a messagebox with System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("message", "title", MessageBoxButtons. <whatever button you want>); Or just MessageBox.Show ... if you're in a form....

Comment: Alright, unfortunately i'm only a beginner at coding and visual basic so if you could point me in the right direction code wise it would be GREATLY appreciated.

This is what the form looks like when the grid is populated, https://gyazo.com/3c8f00ac68f5ecb751a3d3e42bf6db54.

Comment: Actually it's fine, I've found a way of doing it myself, thanks for the help Raymond!

Comment: Happy to help. And good you find the solution yourself. Could you upvote the answer? (Up-arrow on the left). It'll give me more option to help others. Thx.